(standard input) shown instead file name with grep -iHn "ERROR" and a second grep -vH "filter" shows (standard input) and no longer the file name
What I try to do:

Find all log files from this day
Then grep "ERROR" in the files
Then grep -v "Not this line containing the filter" as Filter in result of the first grep command
The first grep command shows the filename/filepath and the row expected
The second grep -v command does not show any longer the file name it show $>(standard input):....

The Problem, remove all resulting rows containing "34" in the Line
[tom@centos7-home-dell ~]$ find /home/tom/tmp/test_grep -name "*.log" -type f | xargs grep -i ERROR 
/home/tom/tmp/test_grep/file1.log:ERROR:12;34
/home/tom/tmp/test_grep/file1.log:ERROR:12
/home/tom/tmp/test_grep/file2.log:ERROR:67890
/home/tom/tmp/test_grep/file2.log:ERROR:12;34
/home/tom/tmp/test_grep/file2.log:ERROR:12
[tom@centos7-home-dell ~]$ find /home/tom/tmp/test_grep -name "*.log" -type f | xargs grep -i ERROR | grep -vH "34"
(Standardeingabe):/home/tom/tmp/test_grep/file1.log:ERROR:12
(Standardeingabe):/home/tom/tmp/test_grep/file2.log:ERROR:67890
(Standardeingabe):/home/tom/tmp/test_grep/file2.log:ERROR:12

My Solution shows expected result but I'm not sure it is o.k. because I use an xargs -0 command. Pleas have a look here:
[thor@centos7-home-dell wildfly]$ find /home/thor/tmp/test_grep -name "*.log" -type f | xargs grep -i ERROR
/home/thor/tmp/test_grep/file1.log:ERROR:12;34
/home/thor/tmp/test_grep/file1.log:ERROR:12
/home/thor/tmp/test_grep/file2.log:ERROR:67890
/home/thor/tmp/test_grep/file2.log:ERROR:12;34
/home/thor/tmp/test_grep/file2.log:ERROR:12

[thor@centos7-home-dell wildfly]$ find /home/thor/tmp/test_grep -name "*.log" -type f | xargs grep -i ERROR | xargs -0 | grep -v 34
/home/thor/tmp/test_grep/file1.log:ERROR:12
/home/thor/tmp/test_grep/file2.log:ERROR:67890
/home/thor/tmp/test_grep/file2.log:ERROR:12


Since you're piping input to the second grep, there's no filename. How do you expect -H to know what the filename was from the previous grep?

I think all you're trying to do is this:
find /home/tom/tmp/test_grep -name '*.log' -type f -exec \
awk -v OFS=':' 'toupper($0) ~ /ERROR/ && !/34/ { print FILENAME, $0 }' {} +

Your existing code, and so the logic copied above, would exclude a line that has a number with 34 contained inside it such as:
/home/thor/tmp/test_grep/file2.log:ERROR:67340

which I suspect isn't what you really want to happen. Given that, you may want to change the /34/ regexp to /[:;]34(;|$)/ or similar to avoid false matches, depending on what you're really trying to do.

I think your crystal ball is hitting on all 8 regarding what is actually intended. Good call.

Hello, it works fine and does the thing I expected. One little issue in the call, the "exec" has to be replaced with "-exec" and all is working. Thanks for your help, now I'll learn awk!

@falcon68 typo fixed. Get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins. It's one of the very few books that everyone who does any programming in Unix should have.
